Time dilation reciprocity
With respect to time dilation, apparently Russian Cosmonaut Sergei Avdeyev, who spent 747 days (64 540 800 seconds) aboard the Space Station Mir which travels at 7600 ms-1 experienced 21 milliseconds less than colleagues on Earth. If Sergei Avdeyev considered himself stationary and the Earth travelling at 7600 ms-1 would he not have experienced 21 milliseconds more than colleagues on Earth?
How does this work?  In a more idealised twin example it may be quite arbitrary as to which party is stationary so when they reunite who is older or younger?

Maybe check the wikipedia page for the twin paradox, it also provides the solution, although I don't know what you mean by a more idealised example

@Damian I mean, for example, two spaceships with relative velocity 0.2 c. It seems either can be considered stationary in which case time dilation slows time for the other.

That is true, however the twin paradox assumes that the twins eventually meet again. In this case at least one of them undergoes acceleration so it is not inertial. Remember that one of the postulates of Special Relativity is that the laws of physics are the same in any inertial system

@Damian Ah yes, Wikipedia says the travelling twin experiences acceleration that the stationary twin does not. So if that was unknown, and an observer just sees them at different constant velocities the observer can just pick the slower one and say the faster one is experiencing slower time, and that will be true but only from the perspective of the observer. Because another observer moving with the fast twin could validly say the opposite.

So unless the twins reunite and we know which who accelerated and decelerated we would never know who is older or younger.

See also How can time dilation be symmetric?

@JohnRennie Thanks
